# WooCommerce wc_logout_url not working when using redirect url

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, logout

I am trying to create a custom logout url using WooCommerce, the below works:

```
$logout = wc_logout_url();
echo '<a href="' . $logout . '"></a>';
```

...but when I try and add a redirect URL as below it doesn't seem to redirect and ends up at the actual logout URL such as:

> http://example.com/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=dd29939e30

...and shows a "page not found 404" and *doesn't* even log the user out.

```
$logout = wc_logout_url(site_url('/'));
echo '<a href="' . $logout . '"></a>';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this didn't work when including a redirect parameter on a standard WooCommerce install. Try using the WordPress function instead of the WooCommerce function.

```
wp_logout_url( '/' );
```